# Nerve: Why not reject?

Tags: plot-explanation, nerve

Is it just for theatrics that in *Nerve*, no one ever even considers pressing the "reject" option on their phone during the game?

Comment: Didn't even realize this question is half a year old lol

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Without it there would be no movie. The movie revolves around going big or going home. Adventurous young adults with no impulse control.

Comment: I feel like there should be constraints, though to at least make sense?

Comment: The movie is an aesop against not thinking things through. We all know exactly what would have happened if they hit no, so there is no reason to show it. They say no and they go home. The end. Boring.

Comment: Ah, but even in universe there are other consequences for saying no. Or have I misremembered the movie?

Comment: @matt_black I think so. The consequences would be for accepting a challenge but then stopping. That's the whole plot "we can't stop because of X". Not for not accepting the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I thought they made it clear that you could reject, or bail, but if you do so, you are out of the running for the top prize.

Sydney bails, after all:
[from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_(2016_film)):

> Jealous at Vee's rise of popularity, Sydney accepts a dare to walk across a ladder suspended between two buildings. Whilst performing the dare, she drops her phone and becomes scared. Sydney bails out and loses the game. Ian takes Vee to Sydney's party and Vee catches her in bed with J.P. After arguing with Sydney, Vee receives and completes the dare on which Sydney bailed.

Comment: she bails, but I didn't see anyone reject